# A condition that the ratio of locations is maximal

Tags: commutative-algebra

Sea $R$ un anillo conmutativo con identidad e $I$ un ideal de $R$ y $m$ un ideal maximal de $R$. Mostrar que $\displaystyle\frac{R_m}{I_m}\neq{0}$ si y solo si $I\subseteq{m}$.
Dm:
$[\Rightarrow{}]$.
Usare la contra reciproca para probar la ida.
Supongamos que existe un $i\in{I}$  tal que $i\not\in{m}$.
Quiero probar que $\displaystyle\frac{R_m}{I_m}=0$ que es equivalente a probar $R_m=I_m$.
$I_m\subseteq{R_m}$.
Ahora el otro contenido. Sea $\displaystyle\frac{r}{u}\in{R_m}$ donde $r\in{R}$ y $u\not\in{m}$.
$\displaystyle\frac{r}{u}=\displaystyle\frac{ir}{iu}$ donde $ir\in{I}$ ya que $I$ideal y $iu\not\in{m}$ ya que $i\not\in{m}$ y $u\not\in{m}$ implica que  $iu\not\in{m}$ pues $m$ es primo ya que es maximal. Solo queria saber si la idea esta bien, muchas gracias.

Comment: Can anyone translate it in English?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know Spanish. But I think my translation below should be more or less accurate.

> "If $R$ is a commutative ring with identity and $I$ an ideal of $R$ and $m$ a maximal ideal of $R$. Show that $\frac{R_m}{I_m}\neq 0$ iff $I \subseteq m$. Proof [$\Rightarrow$] Use proof by contradiction. Let us suppose towards a contradiction that there were an $i\in I$ such that $i\not\in m$. To show that $\frac{R_m}{I_m}=0$ is the same as showing that $R_m=I_m$. $I_m\subseteq R_m$. Now to get the contradiction, if $\frac{r}{u}\in R_m$ where $r\in R$ and $u\not\in m$, then $\frac{r}{u}=\frac{ir}{iu}\in I_m$ where $ir\in I$ because $I$ is an ideal and $iu\in m$ because $i\not\in m$ and $u\not\in m$ implies $iu\not\in m$ since $m$ is a maximal ideal which is therefore a prime ideal. I just wanted to know if the idea is good, thank you very much."

From the title, we know that @tomás was asking about a statement about the quotient ring of localizations at a maximal ideal.

My answer is that the proof provided on the original post is correct.